# Attempting to estimate the expected number of dice rolls needed to obtain all possible sums of two dice when I roll 2 6 sided fair dice

Tags: r, simulation, probability, dice

So I am doing a sample exam question in preparation for my stats exam and I have hit a dead end.

The question is asking:

> If you roll two 6-sided fair dice until you get all possible outcomes (i.e. all sums 2-12 have occurred at least once). Estimate the expected number of dice rolls needed.

This question needs to be answered using a simulation study in R.

So far I have simulated two dice being rolled and have also obtained the sum of each roll. I am unsure how to modify my code to check for expected number of rolls needed to get each sum at least once

My code so far:

```r
d <- data.frame(a=sample(1:6, 1000000, replace=TRUE), 
                b=sample(1:6, 1000000, replace=TRUE)) 
d$sum <- d$a + d$b 
hist(d$sum)
```

Any help would be great :))

Answer (score 4):

We can sample rolling a single die 10 times with the code:

```r
sample(6, 10, TRUE)
```

If we want to sample two dice, we can use `replicate` on this code:

```r
replicate(2, sample(6, 10, TRUE))
#>       [,1] [,2]
#>  [1,]    1    1
#>  [2,]    4    5
#>  [3,]    1    5
#>  [4,]    2    2
#>  [5,]    5    6
#>  [6,]    3    6
#>  [7,]    6    2
#>  [8,]    2    1
#>  [9,]    3    5
#> [10,]    3    5
```

So we can find the row sums of this matrix to get the sums from 10 rolls of 2 dice using `rowSums`:

```r
rowSums(replicate(2, sample(6, 10, TRUE)))
#> [1]  2  9  6  4 11  9  8  3  8  8
```

Now supposing that we simulate 1,000 rolls of two dice in exactly the same way and call the output `throws`.

```r
throws <- rowSums(replicate(2, sample(6, 1000, TRUE)))
```

It is almost certain we will have all of the values 2 - 12 in `throws`, but we can test it out:

```r
length(unique(throws))
#> [1] 11
```

But we can also see that our first 11 throws were not enough to get all 11 different values:

```r
length(unique(throws[1:11]))
#> [1] 10
```

What if we look at the first 100 throws?

```r
length(unique(throws[1:100]))
#> [1] 11
```

So we know that somewhere between 11 and 100 throws were required. Now if we iterate through these throws, then we will find the first point where the number of unique throws was 11:

```r
  for(i in 11:100)
  {
    if(length(unique(throws[1:i])) == 11) break;
  }

i
#> [1] 23
```

Our loop stopped when `i` was 23, meaning that it took 23 throws to get all 11 unique sums from our two dice.

We can wrap all this logic in a little function:

```r
sim <- function() {
  throws <- rowSums(replicate(2, sample(6, 1000, TRUE)))
  for(i in 11:1000)
  {
    if(length(unique(throws[1:i])) == 11) break;
  }
  return(i)
}
```

And we will see we get a different number each time:

```r
sim()
#> [1] 29
sim()
#> [1] 94
sim()
#> [1] 62
```

If we want a feel for the distribution of results of `sim`, we need to put a bunch of its results in a vector. Again, we can use `replicate` here:

```r
vec <- replicate(1000, sim())
```

Now we can see the mean number of throws required:

```r
mean(vec)
#> [1] 59.821
```

And the median

```r
median(vec)
#> [1] 51
```

And a histogram:

```r
hist(vec)
```

[image]

Or a density plot:

```r
plot(density(vec))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, your answer was very thorough and made a lot of sense

Comment: You could significantly optimize sim by having it do one throw at a time and stop as soon as the 11 results have occurred. No need to do 1000 each time, especially when you're t results show the expectation is around 50.

Comment: Also, recalculating unique at each iteration is very inefficient. Can't you have a set that you add to one throw at a time, and stop when the set size is 11?

Comment: Final thing, there's a methodological error: you're cutting off the tail of the distribution. While it will be rare to need more than 1000 throws, it will occur. If I were to run sim a million times to refine my estimate, I'd want those rare cases to be included in the sample space, and I'd still want them for any sample size. If you want to estimate the average from a process, you need to be sure you're sampling from that exact same process.

Comment: @joanis none of what you are saying is technically wrong. If I were writing this in production code, of course I would make it more efficient and add a final check step to cover the infinitesimal possibility of the result being > 1000 (you'd need a lot more than 1 million to find one). My answer here is deliberately pedagogical. If I wrote this function to the best of my technical ability with the intent of optimising efficiency it would be far harder for a beginner to understand. You are welcome to post an answer that takes a different approach.

Comment: Fair point, I just did the math and the tail you're clipping has a probability below 1e-12. And I do like the pedagogy of your answer, it makes it easy for a learner to understand.

Comment: I just added an answer with my suggested pseudocode, but also upvoted your answer because while I would improve your sim function, the rest of your answer is very good.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add a second answer to this question, with additional information meant to complement Allan's answer.

The question calls for a Monte Carlo method: if it's too hard to calculate the distribution of the output of a process, you can run it stochastically a number of times and calculate the average over all the runs. The more precise you want your estimation to be, the more runs you do.

Allan gives an excellent description of the summary statistics, but I would like to propose an improved `sim()` function to use instead. I don't know r, so I'll provide it in pseudo-code.

```
function roll:
    return an int in the range [1, 6] sampled with the uniform distribution

function sim:
    let s = an empty set
    let i = 0
    while size(s) < 11, do:
        let n = roll() + roll()
        add n to s
        i += 1
    return i
```

The code follows the process in the question. Since `s` is a set, its size counts unique results, so its size equals 11 as soon as all results have been obtained.

---

**Addendum**

The above pseudocode implemented in R would be:

```r
roll <- function() sample(6, 1)

sim <- function() {
  s <- numeric()
  i <- 0
  while(length(s) < 11) {
    n <- roll() + roll()
    if(!n %in% s) s <- c(s, n)
    i <- i + 1
  }
  return(i)
}

n_sims <- function(n) sapply(seq(n), function(x) sim())
```

So, for example, to run the experiment 10 times we would do:

```
n_sims(10)
#>  [1]  55  54  31  45  51 118  61  44  63  29
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Nice. Upvoted. I hope you don't mind, but I added the R implementation of your pseudocode including a little test run to show it works. It turns out to be quite slow in R due to the fact that loops are slow in R, but it is also very useful pedagogically.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the r implementation! Interesting that it's slow, but r optimizes vectorized operations so that makes some sense.